# Как посмотреть установленное железо на PC

Tags: python, python-2.x, железо

Как посмотреть установленное железо(процессор, видеокарта и т.п) на PC через python ?

Comment: https://github.com/rdobson/python-hwinfo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для Windows можно использовать

```
import wmi

computer = wmi.WMI()
computer_info = computer.Win32_ComputerSystem()[0]
os_info = computer.Win32_OperatingSystem()[0]
proc_info = computer.Win32_Processor()[0]
gpu_info = computer.Win32_VideoController()[0]

os_name = os_info.Name.encode('utf-8').split(b'|')[0]
os_version = ' '.join([os_info.Version, os_info.BuildNumber])
system_ram = float(os_info.TotalVisibleMemorySize) / 1048576  # KB to GB

print('OS Name: {0}'.format(os_name))
print('OS Version: {0}'.format(os_version))
print('CPU: {0}'.format(proc_info.Name))
print('RAM: {0} GB'.format(system_ram))
print('Graphics Card: {0}'.format(gpu_info.Name))
```

Пример вывода:

> ```
> OS Name: Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate 
> OS Version: 6.1.7601 7601
> CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
> RAM: 15.9443855286 GB
> Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960
> ```

Установить оба модуля:

```
pip install --upgrade wmi
pip install --upgrade pypiwin32
```

Перевод [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38105273/7023590).

Answer (score 2):

Для люниха это можно сделать проще:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import os

pipe_hw = os.popen('lshw','r')
text = pipe_hw.read()
print text
```

Answer (score 0):

Если win, то как вариант, зайди в проводник->этот компьютер (ПКМ по пустому полю)->свойства->диспетчер устройств. Там можно найти твой процессор, видеокарта, wi-fi адаптер. Но это простой способ который помогает найти не полный список комплектующих. Можно еще посмотреть в bios. При вкл компа, зажми либо F2, либо DEL. Там ты даже можешь настроить некоторые параметры. Частоту оперативной памяти например и  многое другое...  А вообще в bios можешь все посмотреть. Ну или же выполнить инструкцию, которую описали выше.

Comment: Извините, а как вы поняли фразу из вопроса: _на PC через python_?