# Как узнать видеокарту использую язык python?

Tags: python

Мне необходимо узнать производителя видеокарты на компьютере, где будет запускаться моя программа. На сколько мне известно, `pywin32` не даёт таких возможностей. Спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38105273/5741205

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как посмотреть установленное железо на PC](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/859759/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pc)